# Redirect url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How would i redirect the following urls via a .htaccess file. The problem i have with these particlular urls is they include special characters:

```
blog/%7Blink%7D
blog/page/2012/%7Blink%7D
blog/page/2013/%7Blink%7D
%7Blink7D%
?cID=225
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^blog/%7Blink%7D?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^blog/page/2012/%7Blink%7D?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^blog/page/2013/%7Blink%7D?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^%7Blink7D%?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^?cID=225?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `%7B` and `%7D` in your regex pattern in your rewrite rules. The URI gets decoded before having rules applied to it, which means you need the `{` and `}` characters:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/\{link\}$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/page/2012/\{link\}$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/page/2013/\{link\}$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^\{link\}$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule (everything after the `?`), so you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cID=225
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you saying this will work `RewriteRule ^blog/\{%7Blink%7D\}?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: @RobMorris this works for me, those 4 rules would replace the 4 rules that you have in your htaccess file that have the `%7B` and `%7D` in the pattern

Comment: @RobMorris No see my answer, you want `^blog/\{link\}$`, The `%7B` ges decoded to `{`, so you **don't want** `%7B`, you **do want** `{`.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the last one `RewriteRule ^?cID=225?$ http://www.mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it the way that you want to but there's a tutorial:

http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-htaccess.phtml

You could also do this with php by either using:

header("location:filename.php");

But you might have to place that code on every webpage though you can just add it to the index page.

If you don't know php all you have to do is:

```
<?php
header("location:newfile.php");
//or you can add a url:
header("location:http://newwebsite.com/");

?>
```

Hope this helps